# find the two points closest to another

Tags: sparql

I have a dataset like this:

```
:p1 :pos 4
:p2 :pos 5
:p3 :pos 9
:p4 :pos 11
```

I want to find the two points closest to another point with a position of 6 (p1 and p2 in my example). I'm trying something like this but it's not working:

```
SELECT ?point ?pos
WHERE{
   ?point :pos ?pos . FILTER(min(abs(?pos - 6)))
}
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions like MIN are applied to groups.  For something like this,  you could use ORDER BY and LIMIT:

```
select ?point where {
  ?point :pos ?pos
}
order by abs(?pos - 6)
limit 2
```

I don't remember offhand what the default sorting order is.  If that query gets you the two points farthest away,  try

```
order by desc(abs(?pos - 6))
```

and

```
order by asc(abs(?pos - 6))
```

to control whether the order is ascending or descending.

Comment: thanks it's work with `order by abs(?pos - 6)` and `order by asc(abs(?pos - 6))`